# Insert Data to mysql database from Associative array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following Associative array

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Liane  Lanford
            [1] => Ken Christenson
            [2] => Melissa Jaramillo
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => $310.40
            [1] => $134.75
            [2] => $951.78
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => $0.00
            [1] => $0.00
            [2] => $0.00
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => $325.92
            [1] => $141.49
            [2] => $999.37
        )
    )
```

There are 3 customers in the array. The number may be 4,5 or more. I want to insert the data from the array to the database like following table

[image]

How can i write the foreach loop. I tried the following but not working

```
foreach ($array as $payment_type => $payment) {
    foreach ($array[payment_type] as $pay => $value) {


        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table(name,subtotal,holdback,total) VALUES ('$pay[0]','$pay[1]','$pay[2]','$pay[3]') ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: I will do that in my final script. This is just for sample checking. Thanks

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't store integers as plain text. It will be harder to query later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is loop the array and then use the index to access all the other values sub array values. I also used the correct prepare and bind mechanism to avoid [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO table (name,subtotal,holdback,total) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

foreach ($array[0] as $idx => $payment) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sdsd', $payment,
                              $array[1][$idx],
                              $array[2][$idx],
                              $array[3][$idx]
                );
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working but running the query 4 times instead of 3 times.

Comment: Woops, fixed the typo

Answer (score 1):

Some code to start with, using prepared statements to prevent SQL-injections:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO table(name,subtotal,holdback,total) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
foreach ($array[0] as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $value,  $array[1][$key], $array[2][$key],  $array[3][$key]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```